# ASP.NET Core identity reset password token invalid in IIS Server

Tags: asp.net-core, token, asp.net-core-identity, reset-password

I am trying to reset password with .NET Core identity. This is why I generate password reset token and send it as an e-mail. The system works fine on localhost, but after uploading it to IIS server, it throws an "Invalid token" error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGcvU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VKWD.png)

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Why the substring?

Comment: because it comes with an extra '\' with the Url.Action method. I use it to remove it.

Comment: No, that's the debugger showing you the escaped string. It's that code that's breaking your token string.

Comment: Okey I changed my code  var ts = Url.Action("ChangePassword", "Account", new { token = tokendecode, email = emaildecode });
                var path = HttpContext.Request.Host + ts;
                var body = $"<a href=\"{path}\">Şifre Sıfırla</a>"; but my problem still continue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem
The reason for the problem was the method I used to encode the token.
I changed my encoding-decoding method

```
--Encode--
byte[] tokenGeneratedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resetToken);
var codeEncoded = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(tokenGeneratedBytes);

--Decode--
var codeDecodedBytes = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(codeEncoded );
var codeDecoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(codeDecodedBytes);
```

Comment: The token already is a string. Why do you do this?